# Multiple interfaces with same name resolution in PHP

Tags: php, scope

I have a third-party library that I am currently using and I am extending their classes fro my project. The problem I am facing is that when I want to upgrade the third-party code, I want to keep the previous versions, this will cause same interfaces with same names, I don't want to modify the third-party libraries and they don't contain namespaces for me to use. Is there a easy resolution for this?

Comment: I don't understand. You want to upgrade AND keep the old version?

Comment: Yes, but not to be used, for rollback/versioning. Problem is from my understanding, unless I explicitly use the include directives there's no way to avoid the problem I foresee.

Comment: For rollback/versionning do a backup of the current lib and replace it with the new one, if you want to rollback you will have to delete the new lib and replace this new lib by the backuped one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right, you should read about [Decorator(Wrapper) pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and adapt it to your situation.

I mean you should create some wrapping class that methods using exact library methods or implements it by its self.

Comment: Yeah that's essentially what I ended up doing. Thanks alot!